# React - calling function props inside setState to get previous state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi is it safe to call function props inside setState function param?
(if onToggle is used by the parent for setting another state), how it's affect the lifecycle / event persist?

example:

```
const myComponent = ({onToggle}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  //use this
  const handleChange = (e) => {
     setActive(prev => {
       onToggle(e, !prev);
       return !prev;
     });
  }

  //instead of this
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setActive(prev => !prev);
    onToggle(e. !active);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onChange={handleChange} />
      {active && <div>ACTIVE</div>}
    </>
  )
}
```

because react says that update state may asynchronous:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Define what you mean by *safe*